# Why is this except being called? - Python

Tags: python, json, exception, except

I have a method that checks a JSON payload for JSON decoding errors, and KeyErrors. For some reason, the `except` statement with the `KeyError` is getting called, but then shows there was in fact, no `KeyError` as the object is `None`. Here is the code:

```
    try:
        test_data = simplejson.loads(self.raw_data) # Loads the data in a dict to test for the right fields
        test_data["test"]

    except simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError as jsonErr:
        print 'JSON Malform Error: ', jsonErr
        pass
        return False

    except KeyError as keyErr:
        print 'JSON Validation Error: ', keyErr
        pass
```

Comment: Remove the `except KeyError` and give the traceback (it's there to answer this question). The `raw_data` could be helpful as well.

Comment: That's exactly why you shouldn't catch exceptions just to print something.

Comment: Is this question similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946768

Comment: @Falmarri I haven't fully implemented these, the prints are just put in to test the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyError is probably raised by `simplejson.loads` and the offending key may really be `None`. Not enough context to say more. If you give the traceback as asked, it will help greatly.

Comment: Here is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./jsontest.py", line 44, in __validate_data
    test_data["test"]

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the traceback should tell you what module the exception was raised in. You might also want to consider using [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) to manually step back and forth to debug future issues like this. Further more, you should inherit from Python's Exception class so you have more control over your own code by raising and excepting.

Utilizing Python's getattr and setattr functions help a lot too:

Using [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) on test_data will let you know when to raise your custom exception in the event that that None is returned.